# Airflow - Task exited with return code 0 but dag is failed

Tags: python, airflow

I'm new to airflow.

I have implemented a condition in my script if all fields are empty we exit the script with return code 0.

```
if df.empty or df.isnull().all().all():
    print("All fields are empty. No update or creation required.")
    sys.exit(0)
```

In Airfow's log it is showing as :

```
[2023-10-03, 17:21:37 AEDT] {local_task_job_runner.py:228} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2023-10-03, 17:21:37 AEDT] {taskinstance.py:2776} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

I don't understand the return code is 0 but the task fail.

How could I implement a way out in my code that does not trigger a fail ?

here is how i declared the dag :

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2023, 10, 2, 21, 0),  # Start date and time in UTC+10 (8:00 AM)
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=4),
 }

dag = DAG(
'ETL_IMPORT',  # Unique identifier for the DAG
default_args=default_args,
description='ETL DAG',  # Description of the DAG
schedule=timedelta(days=1),  # How often the DAG runs (daily in this case)
catchup=False,  # Whether to backfill or not
 )

run_etl_task = PythonOperator(
task_id='ETL_IMPORT_DAG',  # Unique identifier for the task
python_callable=ETL,  # Specify the function to be executed
dag=dag, # Specify the DAG where this task belongs
  
 )
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used  the AirflowSkipException tool

```
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowSkipException 


if df.empty or df.isnull().all().all():
    print("All fields are empty. No update or creation required.")
    raise AirflowSkipException()
```

This skip my execution if the df is empty which is exactly what I wanted.
The dag is marked as Skipped in Airflow after that.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow performs a few more operations after the execution of the operator's execute method and of this code is not executed the task will always be marked as failed. You could change your `sys.exit(0)` by some code who doesn't stops. You can try with ShortCircuitOperator like this:

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2023, 10, 2, 21, 0),  # Start date and time in UTC+10 (8:00 AM)
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=4),
 }
def get_number_func(**kwargs):
    if df.empty or df.isnull().all().all():
        print("All fields are empty. No update or creation required.")
        return False
     else: return True
    
    
dag = DAG(
'ETL_IMPORT',  # Unique identifier for the DAG
default_args=default_args,
description='ETL DAG',  # Description of the DAG
schedule=timedelta(days=1),  # How often the DAG runs (daily in this case)
catchup=False,  # Whether to backfill or not
 )
check_values = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id="frist_check_values",
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=get_number_func,
        op_kwargs={},
        dag=dag
    )
run_etl_task = PythonOperator(
task_id='ETL_IMPORT_DAG',  # Unique identifier for the task
python_callable=ETL,  # Specify the function to be executed
dag=dag, # Specify the DAG where this task belongs
  
 )
check_values>>run_etl_task
```

Comment: In my ETL I need to check if it is empty before doing other process. I don't know by what I could change it to terminate the code and get a success.

Comment: There is an operator name ShortCircuitOperator that let you stop the pipeline for a statement here is the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#shortcircuitoperator)

Comment: I think I understand better now, but the df is downloaded after connecting to an sftp and those task are run in the ETL_TASK, so I need to modify this aswell.

Comment: You can split the tasks, also if theirs a failure in your DAG you will understand better the error